# nil can't be coerced

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, algorithm

I'm trying to return the 12 monthly data, however I keep getting that nil can't be coerced into Integer, this happen when starting with mapping from 0..11 because I use months.ago to group the data which it starts to count from the current month.

```
def yearly_results
    return [] unless user.results.order(id: :desc).where('created_at >= ?', 30.days.ago)

    attributes = [:skin_age, :skin_age_adjusted, :skin_tightness, :purity, :hyperpigmentation_face_score]

    results = []
    #  We create a Hash with every months attributes and values

    (0..11).map do |months_ago|
      month_results = grouped_by_months[months_ago.months.ago.strftime('%Y%m')] || []

      months_with_attr = month_results.reduce({}) do |key, value|
   
        attributes.each do |attr_name|
          key[attr_name] ||= 0
          key[attr_name] += value.send(attr_name)
        end
        key
      end

      if months_with_attr.present?
        months_with_attr.transform_values do |value|
          value.to_f / month_results.count
        end
      end
      results << months_with_attr.presence
    end
    results.reverse
  end
```

This is the error that I keep getting.

```
*** TypeError Exception: nil can't be coerced into Integer

nil
```

Comment: Just a sidenote: usually debugging is the answer, not guessing. If you'd put a breakpoint (byebug/binding.pry/...) in the 1st line of the method in question and traced the execution line by line, you'd find the problematic expression (and the data that cause the exception) in less time than is necessary to create a well-defined question on SO :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you want to use as little SQL as possible i´d propose the following:

```rb
attributes = [:skin_age, :skin_age_adjusted, :skin_tightness, :purity, :hyperpigmentation_face_score]

user.results.order(id: :desc).where('created_at >= ?', 30.days.ago)
.group_by{|result| result.created_at.month }
.transform_values{|results_per_month| attributes.map{|attr| [attr, results_per_month.map(&attr).reduce(&:+).to_f / results_per_month.count] }.to_h }
```

Comment: Interesting but I get and error for some reasons. ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass .transform_values{|results_per_month| attributes.map{|attr| [attr, results_per_month.map(&attr).reduce(&:+).to_f / results_per_month.count] }.to_h } @dario

Comment: I guess some of the values are nil. You can use Array#compact to remove the nil values. "results_per_month.map(&attr).compact.reduce(&:+).to_f". You have to decide if you want to remove the nil values from the result_per_month.count too though.

Answer (score 0):

So if i get this right, you want to calculate the average per month.

I´d suggest to do this with SQL:

```rb
attributes = [:skin_age, :skin_age_adjusted, :skin_tightness, :purity, :hyperpigmentation_face_score]

# Get the average with SQL (for Postgres)
averages = user.results.order(id: :desc).where('created_at >= ?', 30.days.ago)
.group("date_trunc('month', created_at)").select("date_trunc('month', created_at) AS month", attributes.map{|attr| "AVG(#{attr}) AS average_#{attr}" })

# Then group by month
averages.group_by{|res| res['month'].month }
.transform_values{|results_per_month| results_per_month.map{|result_per_month| result_per_month.without('id', 'month') }  }
# => {1 => [{"average_skin_age" => 30, ...}], 2 => [{"average_skin_age" => 32, ...}],}
```

Comment: The goal is to avoid SQL as much as possible. @dario